# Inset paragraph with vertical text next to it

Tags: paragraphs

I'm looking for a way to inset an entire paragraph and add a vertical line to the left of it with some vertical text in the middle (text need not be a variable, there's only going to be 3 or 4 different words in total):

[image]

I have no idea where to start looking. Should I use a table and a Tikz image in the first column? Some sort of mini-page? Is there a package that already does this? I'm using the `framed` package with the `leftbar` environment at the moment, but it doesn't allow me to insert some text into the middle of the bar.

The paragraphs will differ in height, but they'll never span multiple pages so 'in the middle' is a pretty easily defined property.

ps. [This is pretty close](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252462/tikz-vertical-lines-next-to-variable-text), but not quite.

Comment: Please always provide a minimal working example i.e. a complete, minimal document which sets the problem up and gives people something to work from. You can use the packages lipsum, kantlipsum or blindtext for 'dummy' text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help of TikZ:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\verpar[2]{
    \par\vskip1ex
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
paragraph/.style = {inner sep=0pt,
                    text width=\textwidth-\baselineskip}
                            ]
\node (p1) [paragraph] {#2};
\path ([xshift=-0.75\baselineskip] p1.south west) coordinate (p2)
            -- node (p3) [sloped,font=\sffamily] {#1} (p2 |- p1.north);
\draw[very thick] (p2) -- (p3.west) (p3.east) -- (p2 |- p1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\verpar{Text}{\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With**out** the help of  TikZ:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{libertine}
\parindent0pt\parskip.5em
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\def\labelpar#1#2{\vspace{.25\baselineskip}%
\noindent\hfill{\color{gray!50}\vrule width 2pt}\hspace{-2ex}%
\fboxrule2pt\fboxsep.6ex\fcolorbox{white}{white}{%
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\color{cyan}\sffamily\bfseries #1}}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[c]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4ex}\color{red!40!black}
\parfillskip=0pt\sffamily#2\end{minipage}\vspace{.25\baselineskip}\par}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\labelpar{Some text}{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```